# How to check if user pass same input attribute or not in java-8

Tags: java, for-loop, java-8

I have a list of **person class**

```
Person{
 String name;
 Long id;
 
 //getters
 //setters
}
```

Users can pass multiple person input as list, as shown below.

```
[
  {
    "name": "test"
  },
  {
    "name": "test"
  }
]
```

**Use case:** User should pass either name or id for all objects in a list, not both.
If the user passes the name then, all person objects should contain name or vice versa.

for example

**Valid inputs**

```
1. 
[
  {
    "name": "test"
  },
  {
    "name": "test"
  }
]

2.
[
  {
    "id": "test"
  },
  {
    "id": "test"
  }
]
```

**Invalid Input**

```
[
  {
    "name": "test"
  },
  {
    "id": "102"
  }
]
```

One solution is that we can use java loop and check for count

```
int nameFlag = 0;
int idFlag = 0;
for (Person person : personList) {
    if(person.getName() != null){
        nameFlag++;
    }
    
    if(person.getId() != null){
        idFlag++;
    }
}

if(nameFlag >= 1 && idFlag >= 1){
    throw new Exception("Please pass name only or id only, not both");
}
```

Can we use `java-8` stream here?

Comment: for a primitive type, it doesn't really make sense to compare `if(person.getId() != null)`, right?

Comment: yes @Naman, Thanks for notifying, it should be Long.

Comment: ..and with streams, there is not as clean a way as you wrote it with the imperative approach to count both attributes and validate. you can ofcourse stream twice to count each attribute, but then why would you want to do that? That would be something like `long nameFlag = personList.stream().map(Person::getName).filter(java.util.Objects::nonNull).count();
        long idFlag = personList.stream().map(Person::getId).filter(java.util.Objects::nonNull).count();`  and then validate..

Comment: yes, we have that option but is it a good way to use a stream operation two times than a single for loop? I am really not sure about this?

Comment: I really got confused about what should I follow? Single for loop or multiple streams operation, to suit for best performance

Comment: Using two streams would mean iterating twice on the collection, so it is definitely not efficient over a single iteration. I would recommend staying with your actual approach versus choosing to move to streams for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you make it fail fast instead of looping through the entire list.

```
boolean isIdPresent = false;
    boolean isNamePresent = false;
    for (Person person : personList) {
        if (person.getId() != null) {
            isIdPresent = true;
        }
        if (person.getName() != null) {
            isNamePresent = true;
        }
        if (isIdPresent && isNamePresent) {
            throw new Exception("Both Present");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what if both name and Id are present on different objects?. This code will not work in that case. It will work only if same object has name and id

Comment: if you are passing a list of Persons only with Ids or only with names it won't throw any exception. It will throw an exception only when you have a mix of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why do you need to construct `Person` objects this way, but you can try this-

```
List<Map<String,Object>> values = objectMapper.readValue(input, ArrayList.class);
      boolean valid = values.stream()
          .map(Map::keySet)
          .collect(Collectors.toSet())
          .size() == 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually this is just an example based on my code. I have similar requirement so I asked the question using Person class.

Comment: Give it a try and let me know if that works for you.

Comment: I will implement each of the answers in my project, will accept the best suitable answer for the project.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a helper class and use reduce on list:

```
CountPair reduce = personList.stream()
                    .reduce(new CountPair(), CountPair::plus, CountPair::sum);
if(reduce.idCount > 0 && reduce.nameCount > 0) {
    //throw exception
}
```

and the `CountPair` class:

```
class CountPair {
    int nameCount = 0;
    int idCount = 0;

    CountPair sum(CountPair countPair) {
        nameCount += countPair.nameCount;
        idCount += countPair.idCount;
        return this;
    }

    CountPair plus(Person person) {
        idCount += person.getId() == null ? 0 : 1;
        nameCount += person.getName() == null ? 0 : 1;
        return this;
    }
}
```